# pypdf/PyPDF2: Unwanted character substitution in links

Tags: python, pdf, annotations, pypdf

I have a script that converts links in PDFs. The old links point to local files and the new links point to URLs. If the script encounters a link that references a location in the same PDF (ex. Index links) they are copied exactly. The links that should be copied exactly are broken.

I've noticed these index links are having every '.' be replaced with '\' which I'm assuming is breaking the links.

Unaltered link example:

> {'/Border': ['0', '0', '0'], '/Dest': '(M16.9.511.H3.11xy.112114.11715FM079A.Sheet1.Rev30)', '/Rect': ['382.08', '361.08', '421.02', '372.6'], '/Subtype': '/Link', '/Type': '/Annot'}

Link after being copied:

> {'/Border': ['0', '0', '0'], '/Dest': '(M16\0569\056511\056H3\05611xy\056112114\05611715FM079A\056Sheet1\056Rev30)', '/Rect': ['382.08', '361.08', '421.02', '372.6'], '/Subtype': '/Link', '/Type': '/Annot'}

Currently, I'm attempting to build a new link for these broken links, but I'm having issues seeing how these odd `/Dest` values will convert over to the library's Link parameters.

Is there a way to preserve these links?

EDIT:
SOLVED BY USING writer = PdfWriter(clone_from=pdfPath) instead of writer = PdfWriter().
This was a known issue that was patched, I hadn't found the fix at the time of posting.

Comment: \056 is the octal code for the dot. Hence M16.9 becomes M\0569. You don't say what this data structure is. Is it JSON? Why this substitution would be done, I don't know - the dot is an ordinary ASCII code. But it's not wrong.

Comment: Please report this as a bug: https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf/issues

Comment: The links are being printed off through CMD for each annot, print annot. I'm guessing the substitution isn't the cause of the links breaking. Any link I've tried to 'copy as is' appears to be broken, not just these index links. I believe I would have to find a way to convert the M16.9.Etc to an actual page number and create a new link using PyPdf's functions. Maybe not possible, seeing as I'm not noticing any way to pull 'pg. 19' out of 'M16.9.511.H3.11xy.112114.11715FM079A.Sheet1.Rev30'

Thanks for the replies.

Comment: SOLVED BY USING writer = PdfWriter(clone_from=pdfPath) instead of writer = PdfWriter()

Comment: PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf.